# Number of solutions of modular equations

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, generating-functions

I just encountered this problem from Turkey's team selection test:

> $f(a,n)$ is the number of 10-tuples $(x_1,x_2, \cdots, x_{10})$ mod $n$ that satisfies the equation $$x_1x_2...x_{10} \equiv a \textrm{ mod } n.$$ Given $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$, prove that there exists a number $c$ such that $\frac{f(a,cn)}{f(b,cn)}$ is constant.

There is a question I wanted to ask:
Is there a generating function that computes $f(a,n)$? If not then what are the characteristics of this function?
Edit: I have found this equality for smaller tuples but has yet to prove the generalized version: $f(a,mn)=f(a,m)*f(a,n)$, for all $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $gcd(m,n)=1$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: If $n$ is prime $f(a,n)=(p-1)^9$ for $a\ne 0$ and $f(0,n)=p^{10}-(p-1)^{10}$. Likewise in general if $\gcd(a,n)=1$ it's $f(a,n)=\phi(n)^9$.